# Netbeans Library recursive/hierarchical dependency

Tags: java, netbeans, dependencies

I have several projects, **none of them is under Maven framework**.

The projects have dependency between each other, and I want to build very strong abstraction layers.

But I'm facing a problem on the project dependency area.

Lets suppose, with a very simple example;

```
//Project1:
package app;

class Level1 {
   public int lvl1Var = 0;
}
//----------------------------------------------

//Project2:
//This project has Project1 on it dependencies
package app;

class Level2 extends Level1 {
   public int lvl2Var = 1;
}
//-----------------------------------------------

//Project3:
//This project has Project2 on it dependencies
package app;

class LevelUsage{
   public void useMethod(){
      Level2 lvl = new Level2();
      System.out.println( lvl.lvl2Var ); //Compiles correctly
      System.out.println( lvl.lvl1Var ); //Compilation ERROR
   }
}
```

I understand this is normal to happen, as `Project1` is not on `Project3` classpath. Although, I'm talking about a much more complex hierachy tree, and I don't want the High Level Project to add all the subdependency tree below him.

Is there a way (in or out) netbeans, that allows me to stored all the projects dependencies inside itself? For example, create the package of `Project2` containg all the `Project1` so it would be visible for anyone who import the `Project2` it self.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I Believe what you should do here is make these projects individually and create jar files for each one. Then just add them into the Libraries file for the project, this way you only have to call an import packageName.

Another option would be to add the entire project for project1 into project 2 under another package, then it should be referable in the same jar file and then you only have to import the package that it belongs to to refer the project 1's objects and project 2's objects. Or you have one package that has both projects in it such that you have one import that fulfills your needs with multiple class files.

Comment: The point I want to avoid is exactly that `Project3` needs to have `Project2.jar` **AND** `Project1.jar`on its classpath. Im looking for a way that, adding `Project2.jar` implicitly provides you the `Project1` content.

Comment: The only really smart way to do this is to essentially put all the files you think you will ever need in one place. so JDK 1.8 is an entire file that Netbeans looks at full of their jar's. You could just point your Library file to a folder containing the two jar's but nesting jar's inside jars without unpackaging them is not something i'm aware of.

Comment: i have added additional information to the post above